# How to change vowels in a string to a symbol?

Tags: c, loops

I need to change the vowels in a string to a $ using C. I know that I need to use a for loop and I'm pretty sure I'm on the right track but I can't get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char input[50];
    char i;
    int j = 0;

    printf("Please enter a sentence: ");
    fgets(input, 50 , stdin);

    for (j = 0; input[i] != '\0'; j++)      
        if (input[i]=='a'||input[i]=='e'||input[i]=='i'||input[i]=='o'||input[i]=='u')
        {
            input[i]= '$';
            printf("Your new sentence is: %s", input);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

I know my error is not a big one but I just can't see it. This is homework so I don't want a solution as such just some advice so that I can actually learn from this.

Edit:
Thanks for that guys I got rid of 'j' and it now works however when I run the program it outputs a new line for every vowel it changes. How do I code it so that it only outputs the final line i.e. with all of the vowels changed?

Comment: Testing for "aeiou" is not an accurate way to find vowels. For example in the word "gym" there is a vowel sound, yet it doesn't have any of the letters "aeiou"...

Comment: I think he really needs the vowel character, and not the vowel-sound characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You made a small mistake with the index:

```
for (j = 0; input[i] != '\0'; j++)
     ^                        ^
```

should be

```
for (i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

Actually, you can omit `j`:

```
int main(void)
{
    char input[50];
    int i;

    printf("Please enter a sentence: ");
    fgets(input, 50 , stdin);

    for (i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (input[i]=='a'||input[i]=='e'||input[i]=='i'||input[i]=='o'||input[i]=='u')
        {
            input[i]= '$';
        }
    }
    printf("Your new sentence is: %s", input);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I knew it was something minor! Thanks for that. Please see the edit to my question too if you wouldn't mind.... thanks!

Comment: @adohertyd - See the change I made in the location of the print in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

every time you write `input[i];` it should be `input[j]`

Answer (score 0):

Index your input base on the variable from for-loop. Replace your for-loop like this:

```
for (j = 0; input[j] != '\0'; j++)   
{  
        if (input[j]=='a'||input[j]=='e'||input[j]=='i'||input[j]=='o'||input[j]=='u')

        {
            input[j]= '$';
            //printf("Your new sentence is: %s", input); //move this outside the loop
        }  
}
```

So the whole code would be like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char input[50];
    char i;
    int j = 0;
    printf("Please enter a sentence: ");
    fgets(input, 50 , stdin);
            printf ("\ninput: %s", input);

    for (j = 0; input[j] != '\0'; j++)       
    {    

        if (input[j]=='a'||input[j]=='e'||input[j]=='i'||input[j]=='o'||input[j]=='u')
        {
            input[j]= '$';

        }    
    }   
    printf("Your new sentence is: %s", input); 
    return 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String input = "My name is jitender rana"; // here give your input

    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(); // taken to concatenate the string
    for( Int32 i = 0; i<input.Length; i++)
    {
        if ((input[i].ToString().ToLower() == "a") || (input[i].ToString().ToLower() == "e") || (input[i].ToString().ToLower() == "i") || (input[i].ToString().ToLower() == "o") || (input[i].ToString().ToLower() == "u"))
        {
            // output +=  input.Replace(input[i].ToString(), "_");
            sb.AppendLine(input[i].ToString().Replace(input[i].ToString(), "_"));
        }
        else
        {
            sb.AppendLine(input[i].ToString());
        }
    }
    Response.Write(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to take care of uppercase vowels. In the code examples already shared, please include uppercases also for completeness. Also by the way using `switch` construct would be more efficient rather than a series of logical ORs

Answer (score -1):

it's problem with i, j. You have used i , while never incremented it.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

int z=1,i;
char arr[100];
printf("enter a word");
scanf("%[^\n]s",arr);
for(i=0;arr[i]!='\0';i++)
{

 switch(arr[i])
{
 case 'a':
 case 'e':
 case 'i':
 case 'o':
 case 'u':

    printf("%d",z);
    z++;
    break;
    default:
        printf("%c",arr[i]);
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: What does this code dump add to the existing answers? And why is it formatted strangely?