# How can this C project to change vewels to $ be translated into C#?

Tags: c#

Not a problem as much as a curiosity. I came about this old post yesterday and started playing with it in C#. Heres the original post form 2011([How to change vowels in a string to a symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8227296/how-to-change-vowels-in-a-string-to-a-symbol)).

I changed some of the code along with a counter to count the total letters in the word. I am stuck on the if statement. I know this program may not have any real world purpose, but I'm trying to learn C# string manipulation.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a word.");
        string userWord = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("You wrote {0}", userWord);
        Console.WriteLine();

        userWord.ToLower();
        char[] wordArray = userWord.ToArray();


        for (int i = 0; i < wordArray.Length; i++)
        {
            string theLetter = userWord.Substring(i, 1);

            theLetter = theLetter.ToLower();

        if (wordArray[i] == 'a' || wordArray[i] == 'e' || wordArray[i] == 'i' || wordArray[i] == 'o' || wordArray[i] == 'u')
        {
                wordArray[i] = '$';

        }

            string rebuilt = new string(wordArray);

            Console.WriteLine("Your word is now: {0}", rebuilt);
            Console.WriteLine("The total number of letters in your word is {0}", userWord.Length);

        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

I just want to change the vowels to $ or any other letter or symbol and count the digits in the word.

Comment: At the core it is a replace operation. The only big question is what the Vowels are (and if the language even has them). For there I think String.Replace can do it, as can LINQ or a customly written loop. Just avoid the foreach loop as it does not work if the collection is changed.

Comment: myString.Replace(oldChar, newChar)?

Comment: Before delving into more complex topics like string manipulation, please read [a tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/) so you can understand the basics of the language you're using (in this case, C#).

Comment: Thank you for the link. I'll repost this at a later date then. I thought I might be getting a bit too ambitious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem with the C program in the post you linked to is that it only changes the lower-case vowels to '$', not the upper-case ones. The second problem is that strings in C# are immutable, and you already worked around this by changing the word into an array, modifying that, and creating a new string from the modified array.

A method to convert all vowels to '$' might look like this:

```
public static string VowelsToSymbol(string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input)) return input;
    var work = new char[input.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < work.Length; i++)
    {
        var c = input[i];
        switch (c)
        {
            case 'A': case 'E': case 'I': case 'O': case 'U':
            case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
                work[i] = '$'; break;
            default:
                work[i] = c; break;
        }
    }
    return new string(work);
}
```

Slightly less efficient but much better at showing the intent (*what* is being done) instead of the mechanics (*how* is it done):

```
private static char OneVowelToSymbol(char c)
{
    switch (c)
    {
        case 'A': case 'E': case 'I': case 'O': case 'U':
        case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
            return '$';
        default:
            return c;
    }
}

public static string VowelsToSymbolLinq(string input)
{
    return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input) ? input :
        new string(input.Select(OneVowelToSymbol).ToArray());
}
```

If you want to allow for accented characters (or whatever else may count for a vowel in some language other than English), things get ugly quite quickly, and you may be better off using a different method (search the internet for '".NET" isvowel' to find examples).